# How to throw exception of type "template parameter"?

Tags: c++

I have the template header like this:

```
template<class TypeA, size_t tsize=100, class Exc=std::out_of_range>
```

and an add function that throws exception of type Exc:

```
void add(TypeA* objA) {
    if(nelems==capac) {
        delete objA;
        throw Exc e; //the line in question
    }
    nelems++;
    elems[nelems-1]=objA;
}
```

I have the following error message:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘e’
throw Exc e;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `throw Exc{"message"};`

Comment: What are you expecting `e` to do in `throw Exec e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acoording to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw), expression `throw` expects another expression.

But you're providing `throw` expression with `declaration` which is not an `expression`.

try

```
Exc e{"message"};
throw e;
```

or

```
throw Exc{"message"};
```

as Justin suggested to your question.

Comment: why the curly braces? It worked for me with the ( )s just fine since, and I've never seen such an expression, is it a constructor call this way too?

Comment: I forgot to mention ( )s, you can use both { }s and ( )s.
You can call constructor of a class with (), if there's one that has matching arguments.
Creating instant with culry braces is called 'list initialization'. Check details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).